# Volume by disk or washer

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

The volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by
$y=x^2, x=y^2$

about the line $x=−5$

can be computed using the method of disks or washers via an integral

I am doing it like 
 $V=\int_0^1\pi(5+\sqrt y)^2 - (5+y^2)^2\,\text{d}y$.

but I am not getting a correct answer, so anybody could explain what is wrong with the formula

Comment: That's good to know.

Comment: Did you forget to post a question?

Comment: What is your question? if you want to compute the integral, can you try it and update your question with where you are getting stuck exactly?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the volume be instead  $V=\int_0^1\pi(5+\sqrt y)^2 - \pi(5+y^2)^2\,\text{d}y$ ?